# ContinueWith in fire and forget?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, async-await

I have multiple async methods that all make httpclient calls to other servers.  I want to run these at the end of a webapi call and immediately return.  The calls need to each record the time they take and when ALL complete, I need to log those times to a file.  I spent a while tinkering until I got it to work, but I don't know why it works and the other ways don't.

Could you shed some light on this for me?

Here's the basic way that didn't work.  That is, the calls were made, but the LogTimeTaken was not (or at least didn't write the log file).

```
//inside webapi action
        var tasks = new List<Task>
                            {
                                MakeCall1Async(data,timeTaken),
                                MakeCall2Async(data, timeTaken),
                                MakeCall3Async(data, timeTaken)
                            };
                            Task.Run(async () =>
                            {
                                await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
                                LogTimeTaken(timeTaken);
                            });
    //finish webapi action and return
```

Here's the way that did work:

```
    //inside webapi action
Task.Run(async () =>
                    {
                        var tasks = new List<Task>
                        {
                            MakeCall1Async(data, timeTaken),
                            MakeCall2Async(data, timeTaken),
                            MakeCall3Async(data, timeTaken)
                        };
                        await Task.WhenAll(tasks).ContinueWith(t => LogTimeTaken(timeTaken));
                    });
//finish webapi action and return
```

Why?

Also, I am aware of the risks of using fire and forget inside of webapi, and that it won't always run to completion (like when an app pool recycles).  95%+ is good enough in this case.

**EDIT**

I understand everyone's concerns regarding the technology choice.  I may be changing to a pub/sub architecture or use the QueueBackgroundWorkItem.  Given that I only need successful completion 95% of the time, I think running it as I am is fine, however.  The real answer I am trying to get is why the first way fails and the second way succeeds to write to the log.

Comment: timeTaken is a class instance with long properties such as timeTakenForCall1InMs.  That value gets tacked on at the end of Call1Async.

Comment: @DougJones, are you also aware of [QueueBackgroundWorkItem](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/06/04/queuebackgroundworkitem-to-reliably-schedule-and-run-long-background-process-in-asp-net.aspx)?

Comment: @Noseratio I did see [Stephen Cleary's blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html) about it.  It requires upgrading all Dev boxes and servers to 4.5.2.  It's not out of the question, but it is a big deal to update it all.

Comment: @DougJones, if upgrading to 4.5.2 isn't feasible, you still can use `IRegisteredObject` as described by Stephen. You cannot just have unregistered "ghost" fire-and-forget tasks under ASP.NET, spanning life-time of a single HTTP request/response.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at background job schedulers like [hangfire](http://hangfire.io) or [Quartz.net](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net)

Below is a nice blog entry on these solutions.

[How to run Background Tasks in ASP.Net](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx)